# Turn on debug logging in python

Tags: python, logging

I'm trying to turn on debug logging in python 3.5.2:

```
import logging
log = logging.getLogger('test')
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

log.warn('warn')
log.debug('debug')

log.root.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
log.debug('debug again')
```

However, this only prints `warn`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Try this

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Using the root logger `logging` will also print logs from other python libraries. Is there a way to print debug-level logs using a logger obtained via `logging.getLogger()`, insted? Just like in the example provided by the OP.

Comment: @GuidoWalterPettinari this seemed to work for me (in other words, use log instead of logging): `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)` followed by `log = logging.getLogger('test')` followed by `log.debug('debug')`